# change values in arrays until all values are different

Tags: c#, arrays

i am trying to generate 5 random numbers in an array and output them, however i don't want 2 values to be the same, what do i need to add to this code to prevent this?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int count = 0;
        int Randomnum=0;
        int[] num = new int[5];
        Random r = new Random();
        while(count < 5){
            Randomnum= r.Next(1,10);    
            num[count]=Randomnum;
            count = count+ 1;
        }
        foreach(var entry in num)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which programming language do you use? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Typical solution is take an array of all your possible values, **shuffle** it, and then take the first 5 values. It's also convenient that the most common shuffling algorithm would let you stop after filling five positions.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your full set using Enumerable.Range, order them by a random value and get top 5. ie:

```
var numberSet = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
var randomSet = numberSet.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);
foreach (var entry in randomSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
}
```

Comment: This has to generate different guids for the same value for each comparison done within the OrderBy. It addition to being slower to generate all those guids, it can make it possible for the OrderBy to get into a state where it fails to finish and throws an exception (A appears < B and in a later comparison B appears < A, or also A appears < B, B appears < C, C appears < A). More recently there are safeguards within the method to stop this, but it's still not a great option if we care about being _really_ random.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation could be edited so that it adds the new random value (and increments the counter) *only if* `num` does not already contain the value.

Your variables are defined as follows:

```csharp
int count = 0;
int randomNum = 0;

int[] num = new int[5];

Random r = new Random();
```

One way of checking whether or not `num` contains the new value is by using [`Array.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-array-indexof(system-array-system-object)). This method returns the index at which the value you provide is found in the array that you provide. If the value you provide is *not* found in the array, the method will return `-1`.

(Note: `Array.IndexOf()` specifically returns *the lower bound of the array minus 1* when no match is found. Seeing as you populate `num` starting at index `0`, the return value is therefore `-1` in your scenario. More about the computation of an array's lower bound [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound?view=net-6.0)).

The implementation of your `while` loop could thus be adjusted to:

```csharp
while (count < 5)
{
    randomNum = r.Next(1, 10);

    if (Array.IndexOf(num, randomNum) < 0)
    {
        num[count] = randomNum;
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

---

An alternative to using `Array.IndexOf()` is to use [`Enumerable.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-contains-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-0)) from the *System.Linq* namespace. I find it to be more readable, so I just thought I'd mention it.

```csharp
//using System.Linq;

while (count < 5)
{
    randomNum = r.Next(1, 10);

    if (!num.Contains(randomNum))
    {
        num[count] = randomNum;
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

---

That being said, you may want to consider using a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) rather than an array for this scenario. A `HashSet` can only contain distinct values, which is what you want to achieve.

`HashSet`'s [`.Add()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-6.0) actually checks whether your `HashSet` already contains the value you are trying to add. If it does, the value will *not* be added again.

- Due to this behavior, you can call `.Add()` for every random value that you generate, without manually having to check for existence beforehand.
- Another beneficial side effect of this is that your `count` and `randomNum` variables are no longer necessary.

Using a `HashSet` rather than an array, your code (prior to the code that prints the result to the console) could be implemented as follows:

```csharp
//using System.Collections.Generic;

HashSet<int> num = new();

Random r = new Random();

while (num.Count < 5)
{
    num.Add(r.Next(1, 10));
}
```

---

Example fiddle with all three implementations [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzQFbj).